# How to specify the position of CollapsingToolbar (or Appbar) in android

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have a image wich has a parallax effect by using CoordinatorLayout and CollapsingToolbar in my application.

I want to know if its possible to define the position of the CollapsingToolbar (or AppBar) to show only half the image, so the user is able to scroll down and see the whole image.

Explaining better, if I have an image of height 400dp , there is a way to tell to collapsing toolbar to programatically scroll to 200dp height, and the user be able to scroll down and see the full image. (Like profile in whatsapp).